# How to properly attach an Event Listener to global 'window' in Angular 6+?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, iframe, postmessage

**Background**

Our `Angular 6` application contains an `iframe` with some 3rd party data. To enable a safe cross-domain communication the child iframe posts messages to parent Angular application using [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API. In order to receive those messages parent window must attach an event listener like `window.addEventListener("message", callback)` to listen for [MessageEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent)

**Question**

I need to listen for message events inside Angular component and it's not obvious for me how to properly access global `window` in Angular way. The only solution I imagine at the moment is:

1. Create an Angular Service called `MessageListenerService` with the following method:

`function listenForMessageEvent(callback) {
  this.renderer.listen('window', 'message', callback);
}`

**Note:** `this.renderer` here is [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) from Angular core.

2. Just use `MessageListenerService.listenForMessageEvent()` in my custom component.

I feel like it's not the standard approach in Angular world. Could someone advise any best practise here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Angular" way of doing this is to use `HostListener`

https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener

Here is a stackblitz example for your review. Open console and review the log when using keys on the keyboard to trigger events.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-1